# The forty days and forty nights of Moses story in Deuteronomy 9:18?

Tags: exodus, deuteronomy

> Verse-A, Exodus 24:18
>  Then Moses entered the cloud as he went on
>   up the mountain. And he stayed on the mountain **forty days and forty
>   nights**.

The information above took place when Moses received the first stone tablets.

> Verse-B, Exodus 34:28
>  And he was there with the LORD **forty days
>   and forty nights**; he did neither eat bread, nor drink water. And he
>   wrote upon the tables the words of the covenant, the ten commandments.

The information above took place when Moses received the second stones tablets.

So, two times Moses went up to the mountain. The first time is to receive the first stone tablets and the second time is to receive the second stone tablets. Each time he stay there for forty days and forty nights (according to me after reading those verses).

> Verse-C, Deuteronomy 9:18
>  And I fell down before the LORD, **as at the
>   first**, forty days and forty nights: I did neither eat bread, nor
>   drink water, because of all your sins which ye sinned, in doing
>   wickedly in the sight of the LORD, to provoke him to anger

My question (because of the bold sentence `as at the first`) :
*Is the "forty days and forty nights" in verse-C the second time Moses up at the mountain as mentioned in verse-B ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Deuteronomy 9:18 refers to the second time Moses went up to get the law from God. Deuteronomy 9:9-11 are about the first time Moses got the law. Deuteronomy 9:15-17 are about Moses' coming down from the mountain, seeing the people's sin, and breaking the tablets of the law. And then comes the verse you quoted, Deuteronomy 9:18.